# Does PHP's spl_autoload_register Load Only Necessary Classes?

Tags: php, spl, spl-autoload-register, spl-autoloader

I've found numerous stackoverflow pages claiming that spl_autoload_register only loads necessary classes ([__autoload vs include family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6437134/autoload-vs-include-family/6437316#6437316) for example), but is there documentation or proof of this? I checked php.net and couldn't find anything in their documentation. I also did a Google search and couldn't find an official answer.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: @hek2mgl, you should provide the line the OP needs.

Comment: I've viewed (php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) numerous times and couldn't find anything that states whether unneeded classes are NOT included, thereby improving performance.

Comment: @JoshDavis Of course unneeded classes will not being included

Comment: @hek2mgl - Can you show me where or how you know this?

Comment: That's by design. The autoload function will be called every time a class will be accessed which has not being explecitely included using `include_once` or `require_once`. So why should the autoload method include unnecessary classes?